# Can't get JSON object into HTML correctly

Tags: jquery, json

I am probably doing something extremely dumb and I know this has been asked a thousand different ways.I want to get the info, title, and description into my HTML. It's just repeating the same info in each div and it's not populating the other nodes. My JSON object, the $.each loop and HTML are below.THanks

```
var data = {
"available": true,
"screens": [{
        "id": "s01",
        "type": "Selector",
        "config": {
            "views": [{
                "id": "sintel",
                "type": "selectorItem",
                "thumbnail": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/sintel/assets/img/thumb_sintel.png",
                "title": "Sintel",
                "description": "Small video. HTML5, native controls, start poster. Bottom, right social. Video + grid",
                "info": "00:51"
            }, {
                "id": "bbb",
                "type": "selectorItem",
                "thumbnail": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/bbb/assets/img/thumb_bbb.png",
                "title": "Big Buck Bunny",
                "description": "Large video. HTML5, custom controls, social hover. Video + replay",
                "info": "00:33"
            }, {
                "id": "walle",
                "type": "selectorItem",
                "thumbnail": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/walle/assets/img/thumb_walle.png",
                "title": "WALL-E",
                "description": "Small video. Youtube, custom controls. Left social. Video + carousel.",
                "info": "02:30"
           }]
        }
    }
]
}

$.each(data.screens, function(index, element) {

       $(".container").find('.card-info').text(element.config.views[0].info);
       $(".container").find('.card-title').text(element.config.views[0].title);
       $(".container").find('.card-description').text(element.config.views[0].description);
});

<!--This is the HTML-->
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <div  class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" 
            </div>
             </div><!-- card image -->
             <div class="card-content">

                <span class="card-info">  </span>
                <span class="card-title"> </span>     
                <span class="card-description"> </span>                    
             </div><!-- card content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <div  class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
             </div>
             </div><!-- card image -->
              <div class="card-content">
              <span class="card-info">  </span>
                <span class="card-title"> </span>     
                <span class="card-description"> </span>   
            </div><!-- card content -->
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What I think you want to do is `data.screens.forEach(screen => ... )` to construct rows and `screen.config.view.forEach(view => ...)` to construct each row's cells. What you're missing is that you need to dynamically revise the HTML based upon these loops.  Commonly in HTML, this would take the form of a `<TABLE>`, `<TR>` and `<TD>`. You may wish to review jQuery's append method to see how this can be done. https://api.jquery.com/append/. HTH.

Comment: Thank you, I know `append` but i guess I am confused as to why it's inserting the same content. Can you provide an example against mine?

Comment: I'll add an answer with some code.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are inserting data into the same div. You need to generate html rows inside your loop which will be then appended/inserted into the container.

```js
var data = {
"available": true,
"screens": [{
        "id": "s01",
        "type": "Selector",
        "config": {
            "views": [{
                "id": "sintel",
                "type": "selectorItem",
                "thumbnail": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/sintel/assets/img/thumb_sintel.png",
                "title": "Sintel",
                "description": "Small video. HTML5, native controls, start poster. Bottom, right social. Video + grid",
                "info": "00:51"
            }, {
                "id": "bbb",
                "type": "selectorItem",
                "thumbnail": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/bbb/assets/img/thumb_bbb.png",
                "title": "Big Buck Bunny",
                "description": "Large video. HTML5, custom controls, social hover. Video + replay",
                "info": "00:33"
            }, {
                "id": "walle",
                "type": "selectorItem",
                "thumbnail": "http://test-cdn.selectablemedia.com/test/a/walle/assets/img/thumb_walle.png",
                "title": "WALL-E",
                "description": "Small video. Youtube, custom controls. Left social. Video + carousel.",
                "info": "02:30"
           }]
        }
    }
]
}

$.each(data.screens[0].config.views, function(index, element) {
console.log(element.info);
console.log(element.title);
console.log(element.description);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over your array(s) but, instead of just replacing the single `<div>` elements with multiple values (one after the other), you need to create multiple elements.

```
<div id="results"/>
```

and:

```
let screenRows = data.screens.map(screen => {
  let viewRows = screen.config.views.map(view => `<tr><td>${view.id}</td><td>${view.description}</td></tr>`);
  let viewTable = `<table>${viewRows}</table>`;
  return `<tr><td>${screen.id}</td><td>${screen.type}</td><td>${viewTable}</td></tr>`;
});
let screenTable = `<table>${screenRows}</table>`;
$("#results").append(screenTable);
```

It's very hacky but it works ;-)